# Showing online offline of a device with date and status js jquery d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have been trying to create a bar with this kind of data as

```
"data":[
         ["2016-12-18 00:25:20",1],
         ["2016-12-19 00:25:20",0],
         ["2016-12-19 00:26:18",1],
         ["2016-12-19 05:50:21",0],
         ["2016-12-19 05:51:19",1],
         ["2016-12-20 05:25:46",0],
         ["2016-12-20 05:27:03",1],
         ["2016-12-20 05:50:17",0],
         ["2016-12-20 05:51:17",1],
         ["2016-12-21 03:25:43",0],
         ["2016-12-21 03:26:42",1],
         ["2016-12-21 05:50:27",0],
         ["2016-12-21 05:51:41",1],
         ["2016-12-22 03:25:30",0],
         ["2016-12-22 03:26:41",1],
         ["2016-12-22 05:50:22",0],
         ["2016-12-22 05:51:22",1]
     ]
```

In this date and time is that period when the device came online or offline where 1 and 0 representing online and offline respectively, I have been using https://github.com/flrs/visavail d3j implementation to get such results as

[image]

The idea is has been implemented in https://uptimerobot.com/ .

The flrs's visavail is not giving proper results at the moment, I just keen to know if anyone has some other ideas about it. or know some d3 implementation to show such bar, or if we take d3 out of this and do that in only Jquery or JS, is that possible to create such bar? with this kind of data?

Comment: can you explain better what do you mean by "is not giving proper results at the moment"? Do you have any errors or smth like this?

Comment: https://github.com/flrs/visavail/issues/6

Comment: thats the issue I have created and also, the gist i have made in the last is not showing any red line which it should. according to the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that complicated, you could do it with simple `line` elements.

In this demo, I'm painting *all* the lines, but setting the opacity according to the online/offline status:

```js
var data = [
    ["2016-12-18 00:25:20", 1],
    ["2016-12-19 00:25:20", 0],
    ["2016-12-19 00:26:18", 1],
    ["2016-12-19 05:50:21", 0],
    ["2016-12-19 05:51:19", 1],
    ["2016-12-20 05:25:46", 0],
    ["2016-12-20 05:27:03", 1],
    ["2016-12-20 05:50:17", 0],
    ["2016-12-20 05:51:17", 1],
    ["2016-12-21 03:25:43", 0],
    ["2016-12-21 03:26:42", 1],
    ["2016-12-21 05:50:27", 0],
    ["2016-12-21 05:51:41", 1],
    ["2016-12-22 03:25:30", 0],
    ["2016-12-22 03:26:41", 1],
    ["2016-12-22 05:50:22", 0],
    ["2016-12-22 05:51:22", 1]
];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

data.forEach(d => d[0] = parseTime(d[0]));

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d[0]))
    .range([0, 300])

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var lines = svg.selectAll(".lines")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("y1", 50)
    .attr("y2", 70)
    .attr("x1", d => scale(d[0]))
    .attr("x2", d => scale(d[0]))
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("opacity", d => d[1] ? 1 : 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <rect x="0" y="50" width="300" height="20" fill="lightgreen"></rect>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**: Reading again your question, now I see that you have changing intervals: each date shows when a period starts and the previous one ends. My bad.

Here is another snippet. This is (also) a very simple code, in which I paint the rectangles starting at a given date and ending at the next date. The rectangle is "green" for online periods, and "red" for offline periods:

```js
var data = [
    ["2016-12-18 00:25:20", 1],
    ["2016-12-19 00:10:20", 0],
    ["2016-12-19 00:36:18", 1],
    ["2016-12-19 05:50:21", 0],
    ["2016-12-19 05:59:19", 1],
    ["2016-12-20 05:25:46", 0],
    ["2016-12-20 05:37:03", 1],
    ["2016-12-20 05:50:17", 0],
    ["2016-12-20 06:58:17", 1],
    ["2016-12-21 03:25:43", 0],
    ["2016-12-21 03:36:42", 1],
    ["2016-12-21 05:50:27", 0],
    ["2016-12-21 06:09:41", 1],
    ["2016-12-22 03:25:30", 0],
    ["2016-12-22 04:26:41", 1],
    ["2016-12-22 05:50:22", 0],
    ["2016-12-22 05:51:22", 1]
];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

data.forEach(d => d[0] = parseTime(d[0]));

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d[0]))
    .range([0, 500])

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("x", d => scale(d[0]))
    .attr("width", (d, i) => {
        if (data[i + 1]) {
            return scale(data[i + 1][0]) - scale(d[0])
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    })
    .attr("fill", d => d[1] ? "lightgreen" : "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500">
</svg>
```

Comment: To the editor of my answer: `selectAll` for an enter selection **doesn't** need the selected element to exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you explain a little? red lines are offline but those green ones? and the range between those lines?

Comment: Also as you see, you are starting and ending with red where in data its 1 and 1 start and end for online

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I got your problem wrong in the first snippet. Check my edit.

Comment: Okay Thanks, Am accepting your answer, but am slight confuse :( and Dont understand it actually that, how you presented the gap between red and green, few reds are too dark and others not, I need to study d3j, but thanks again

Comment: That's because of your data: the chart goes from the first date to the last date, that is, a time period of around 4 days. But you have offline periods of just few minutes! That's why some reds are so thin, and they seem to be paler (the browser cannot draw something like a tenth of a pixel). I changed the data, to make the offline periods bigger (and the red rectangles wider). But **all** red rectangles are the same colour!

Comment: One question can we do it , for exmaple. give the bar total length of a week, and then go through the data which will be surely between a week,, and then color that bar with that data, ?

Comment: will you please show me that one as well? as in the question the link from github one is doing that. bar start from a week before date and end at present one.

Comment: It's a lot of code for me to write right now. I suggest you post **another** question, you'll get more help that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322610/creating-bar-in-d3js-while-representing-a-week I have posted one :)

Comment: I think you are the only chap who will be interested to answer that one as well :D